# I get `System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox` instead of TextBox value

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008

Gooday. Could you help me figure out please why I get this: `System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox`  on Label1:

```
DataListItem item = DataList1.Items[0];
TextBox nume = (TextBox)item.FindControl("numeTb");
Label1.Text = nume.ToString();
```

I specify that the numeTb element is put like this in the ASPX file:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="numeTb" runat="server" Width="400px" 
Text='<%# Eval("nume") %>' DataTextField="nume" DataValueField="nume"></asp:TextBox>
```

I just added the DataTextField bits thinking might help, but no. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

You need to use the `Text` property

Change this line

```
 Label1.Text = nume.ToString();
```

to

```
 Label1.Text = nume.Text;
```